# How to highlight the background of a UIButton when it is clicked and "unhighlight" it?

Tags: swift, background, uibutton, highlight

I am trying to create 4 `UIButtons` that highlight and stay highlighted when they are clicked. The only problem is I need only one UIButton to be Highlighted at a time. So, if there is a `UIButton` highlighted already, I need it to be "unhighlighted" and highlight the `UIButton` I clicked. I have tried to do this before and failed. Please help me with this problem.
I am using the Swift coding language to do this.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create your `UIButton`s using Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes. Should I connect them as IBActions or declare them in the ViewController.swift and connect them.

Answer (score 2):

If you give this answer an upvote, remember to upvote dasblikenlight's answer as well.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Connect all 4 buttons to this outlet
    @IBOutlet var radioGroup: [UIButton]!

    // Connect this action to all 4 buttons
    @IBAction func radioGroupClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Unhighlight all buttons
        unhighlightRadioGroup()

        // Highlight the one being clicked on
        highlightRadioGroup(sender as! UIButton)
    }

    // Set all 4 buttons in unselected state
    func unhighlightRadioGroup() {
        for button in radioGroup {
            button.selected = false
        }
    }

    // Set one button in the selected state
    func highlightRadioGroup(button : UIButton) {
        button.selected = true
    }

}
```

Comment: All the buttons start unselected. Will this make a difference in the code?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but it doesn't hurt to try

Comment: How can I make a next button that uses the button that is selected to pick the array associated with each button?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an `IBOutletCollection`. Command-drag one of the buttons into the view controller code, and choose creating of an `IBOutletCollection` on drop, and name your collection something - say, `radioGroup`. Then control-drag the remaining three buttons into the same  `IBOutletCollection`.

Next thing is to add a method to un-highlight all buttons in your `radioGroup`. This can be done with a simple loop.

Finally, add calls to `unhighlightRadioGroup` from the event handler of your buttons. Event handler should first call your `unhighlightRadioGroup` method, and then highlight the `sender` received in the event handler.

Comment: Please post the code for this. I am unsure how to some of the things you said to do.

Comment: @Buster I posted this answer during a transfer between flights, so I did not have time to add code. It looks like Zoff Dino has posted relevant code for this, so at this point you should be fine, as far as the code goes, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var buttonsArray: [UIButton] = {
    var buttons = [UIButton]()
    let firstButton = UIButton()
    let secondButton = UIButton()
    let thirdButton = UIButton()
    let fourthButton = UIButton()

    buttons = [firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton, fourthButton]
    return buttons
}()   

private func setupButtonMethods() {
    filteredButtons[0].addTarget(self, action: #selector(firstButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    filteredButtons[1].addTarget(self, action: #selector(secondButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    filteredButtons[2].addTarget(self, action: #selector(thirdButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    filteredButtons[3].addTarget(self, action: #selector(fourthButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

private func setupHiglightedStateOnButton(button: UIButton) {
    for btn in buttonsArray {
        btn.isSelected = false
        btn.backgroundColor = .gray
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    button.isSelected = true
    button.backgroundColor = .yellow
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

@objc func firstButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    setupHiglightedStateOnButton(button: sender)
}

@objc func secondButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    setupHiglightedStateOnButton(button: sender)
}

@objc func thirdButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    setupHiglightedStateOnButton(button: sender)
}

@objc func fourthButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    setupHiglightedStateOnButton(button: sender)
}
```

> remember to call setupButtonMethods() inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: Probably not the easiest way on the world but it's my small solution :)